# Returning a String from JpaRepository Native Query?

Tags: java, sql, string, repository, spring-data

I am trying to use a `native query` to return the value of a certain `column` within my table.

I know that native queries can be used to return objects, i.e. in this example?:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

However, how would I write this to return the value of the **one column**? I.e. if I wanted to just return the name (string) of the user, **not** the 
user `object`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT u.name FROM USERS u WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  String findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use e.g. u.name?

Comment: Good point. It's not. `SELECT name FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?1` is correct too.